# In views, how can you link "read more" to the webform submission?

Tags: 7, views, webforms

I have created a view from webform submissions but some of the answer in the submission are too long. I tried to add a "read more" link in the view to be able to view the rest of the answer but I'm not sure which path to give it. When I do node/[nid], as you would with a content type, it goes back to the blank webform.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the link should be `node/%nid/submission/%sid/view`.

Where `%sid` is the webform submission id.